# What if two persons on the Patent had nothing to do with the development or invention of the patent

Tags: licensing

In reference to the patent: [US8689717](https://www.google.com/patents/US8689717)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents! I was a bit unclear here on what you meant. Where are the people listed? Are they assignees? Inventors?

Answer (score 1):

Correct inventorship is critical to the validity of a patent.  Fenwick & West have a nice explanation of this:  [Correct Inventorship](https://www.fenwick.com/FenwickDocuments/Correct_Inventorship.pdf).

There is a body of case law about actions to include legitimate inventors who were not listed as such, in which the new inventor acquires independent right to license the patent.   Similarly there is case law about inappropriate and incorrect listing of inventors who can be shown not to have contributed, which in some cases can lead to invalidation of the patent.